# Error establishing a database connection during wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

[image]

> I have installed Wordpress in WAMP server but it doesn't install.
>   `wp-config.php` file is not in folder.
>
> I have created a database and add new user.

**The name of the database for WordPress**

```
definewordpress('DB_NAME', '');
```

**MySQL database username**

```
define('DB_USER', 'root');
```

**MySQL database password**

```
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

**MySQL hostname**

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: Have you created database in phpmyadmin?

Comment: ya i have create a database

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

You install wordpress on localhost or on live server

```
define('DB_NAME', 'Your Database here');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'Your UserName Here');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Your Password Here');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Do you give all things in wp-config.php files as above

- change name wp-config-sample to wp-config

Comment: i was made changes in all this feilds

Comment: Your wp-config file destination

Comment: try this 
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');
instead of define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); might be it working for you 
or add 
define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );

Comment: change name of wp-config-sample to wp-config

Comment: but anathore error generated wp-config-sample is required.

Answer (score 0):

Please use something like this.it will work

```
define('DB_NAME', 'Database name here');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Username will be root and password will be empty

Comment: ya sure.but wp-config file is not there the file is wp-config-sample.php

Comment: When you install the WordPress. You got the screen of entering database, username, password, prefix and hostname

Answer (score 0):

If wp-config file is not created automatically then your site(folder) under wamp is not writable and don't have permissions.
So Please give permissions.

755 to all folders
644 to all the files

Rest all is good at you part ...also you can rename the sample file to wp-config.php and update the details same as you did.

Also make sure you have no user name and password set for database. If you have created then use then instead of root and password in place of password.

You can also try (127.0.0.1) in place of **localhost**

check you phpmyadmin for database if it exist.

hope it helps.